# An error ocurred while starting the kernel Spyder when restarting with Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, spyder

Whenever I restart kernel while using Pytorch I got this error. How to resolve this. I tried to restart again, create new console but the error persist until I restart the spyder by closing and opening it again

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 287, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 17, in 
import pdb
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 76, in 
import code
File "D:\Datasets\Image dataset\Xray\code.py", line 77, in 
train_loss=fit_train(batch)
File "D:\Datasets\Image dataset\Xray\code.py", line 66, in fit_train
img1_emb,img2_emb=model(img1.to(device)),model(img2.to(device))
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "D:\Datasets\Image dataset\Xray\cnn_model.py", line 37, in forward
x=self.relu(self.conv1_2(x)) 
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 423, in forward
return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 420, in _conv_forward
self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 294.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.37 GiB already allocated; 72.82 MiB free; 4.42 GiB rese
```

rved in total by PyTorch)

Comment: Do you have some code running? Or is it just when starting the kernel without running any code?

Comment: it is after once in run some code, and when it give memory error especially.

Comment: Then you should probably edit your question and add this code, so we can have a look.

Comment: "Out of memory" is a pretty common message amongst PyTorch users, to avoid this you can always send your data to CUDA in smaller batch sizes rather than sending them all at once!

Comment: @Sahil_Angra issue is not this, the issue is that I cannot restart spyder after that